# Science-fantasy book series where underground machines kept the world alive powered by the big evil

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been trying to remember the name of this series of books I read several years ago (might have been around 2010+-). Unfortunately, I don't remember too much or might be mixing things up.

I believe it took place in some "dying world" fantasy setting where technology relics of the past where seen as magic. Apart from that I remember that the world was kept alive by machines underground and the big evil turned out to be running those machines. I also believe it featured creators/gods that abandoned said world.  I think the main antagonist was a failed "genetic" experiment left by the creators

Answer (score 6):

This could be *[Strata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strata_(novel))* by Terry Pratchett, written in 1981, before *The Colour of Magic*.  Like the later Discworld novels, it takes place on a flat planet, although one of a science fiction, rather than fantasy, nature.  Beneath the disc is an extensive mechanical architecture that keeps the whole thing running, including simulating both mundane and magical phenomena.  There are fake sun, moon, stars, and planets orbiting around the disc; the characters also meet a muscular winged demon, who can only actually fly because an underground teleportation system automatically teleports him upward many times per second.  If anyone tried to dig down into the underground mechanisms, the systems produce holograms of horrible monsters to drive the interlopers away.  However, the whole system is running down.

On an island at the center of the disc, the main characters (the human Kin Arad and two other intelligent aliens) find that the disc was created by the very same godlike being who made the whole universe.  The computer that largely runs the disc reveals that Kin Arad had been lured there by a human criminal who had previously located the disc and wanted to plunder its riches.  He had been part of an early experiment in pre-FTL travel, placed on a ship in suspended animation until the ship got close enough to another planet to wake him up.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That does sound similar, but it's not quite what i'm looking for.